# working with views using rails new backend Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I started with rails 5, I am noob in rails. I want to create a simple API, but I want to have views (such as active admin). I found the autogenerated API using the code 'rails new backend' command.

Is there a way to autogenerate views and not only Json response using this command?

Comment: I would recommend reading the docs, and going through the tutorials on the official rails site. Start here for generating stuff http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: @user1875195 thanks! I went to this docs, but I want to autogenerate the API, without doing by my own. Is that ok?

Comment: I don't follow, are you trying to autogenerate just the controller? Or everything? It states in the docs everything that gets generated in the output.

Comment: I think what you're asking is if you can serve both render json responses and views from a controller? If that is the case, read up on rendering here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: He's creating an API, by default Rails API would probably return JSON, whereas he also wants a page to admin the app, what's the best way to do, am I right?

Comment: Everything, that means only views, because the models and API were already built, Make sense?

Comment: @oreoluwa Yes, you are right, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

I may not have the answer, but [I found this which may be a better answer to the question.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/3vayy6/can_activeadmin_be_used_with_rails_api/)

Approach:

Subclass `APIController` from `ActionController::API`, rather than `ApplicationController`, make `ApplicationController` inherit from `ActionController::Base`.

You may include the `Rack::MethodOverride` middleware.

I'd try to build something similar to this in the coming week, largely to learn about `ActiveAdmin` and some newer Rails methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard ActiveAdmin interface won't work with an API app because  those (by definition) cut away the presentation layer, i. e. all the gems for views/js/etc.

But it will work the other way around: --api is almost a subset of a full rails application and comes with, for example, json rendering by default. I say 'almost' because a few details need to be adjusted, such as (probably) cors and csrf settings.

You can get get to a functioning rails 5 app serving .json in about a minute:

```
rails new foo
rails db:setup
rails generate scaffold Post title:string body:text
rails db:migrate
rails server
-> http://localhost:3000/posts/index.json
```

Apart from reading the docs and a few tutorials, you should generate two applications, one with --api and one without, add model/views/controller scaffold and just walk through the diff. Then you can mix&match the customizations for api-mode into your app.

Answer (score 0):

## Enabling Active Admin for Rails 5 API application

### 1. Separate view-rendering controllers from API controllers

- Active Admin requires `ApplicationController` to inherit from `ActionController::Base`.
- API controllers should still inherit from `ActionController::API`

Use the following

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

class APIController < ActionController::API
```

where any API-specific controllers inherit from `APIController`.

### 2. Enable `flash` middleware

Inside `config/application.rb`

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    # add this =>
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

## 3. (For Devise authentication) Enable session management

Inside `config/application.rb`

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    # add these =>
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
  end
end
```

Here is the [full guide](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/how-to-add-active-admin-to-a-rails-5-api-application.html?utm_source=stackoverflow)